# unexpected symbol near '='

Tags: lua

```
function currentLocation()
 currentX, currentY = GetMouseremove_style_tag> currentY = height*currentY/65535
 currentX = width*currentX/65535
 currentX = math.floor(currentX)

 currentY = math.floor(currentY)
 return currentX, currentY

end
```

unexpected symbol near '='

i dont know why do not work

Comment: My first guess would be that `remove_style_tag>` part.

Comment: What line is the error on?

Answer (score 1):

On the second line of your script you have a syntax error.